# Total achievement points for Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I'm a bit of an achievement whore.... I've noticed that there are achievements linked in the game.

What is the total number of achievement points that you can earn in Diablo 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a total of 450 achievements (including *Feats of Strength*) in Diablo III (currently, they might add more later in expansions).

*Feats of Strength* give you **0** points and there are 9 of them.
Twelve achievements give you **20** points each.
The rest (429) gives you **10** points each.

Therefore: `9 * 0 + 20 * 12 + 10 * 429 = 4530` points in total.

Out of the 4530 points, however, there are class specific achievements which obviously you can't all get on one class.

- **Barbarian:** 12 achievments (120 points)
- **Demon Hunter:** 14 achievements (140 points)
- **Monk:** 10 achievements (100 points)
- **Witch Doctor:** 10 achievements (100 points)
- **Wizard:** 12 achievements (120 points)

The achievements are shared across all your characters on the same account, so you don't have to get them again when you create a new char (unlike WoW, mumbling....)

Comment: Also, some achievements you can only get by leveling up several characters, as well as playing hardcore.

Comment: There's now also another Feat of Strength for registering a copy of the Mists of Pandaria Collector's Edition.

Comment: You are welcome to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually 4560. I have got 4530 right now, and there are still 3 achievements left which will give me 10 points each.